# C# progress bar control is hard to use?

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know how to start and stop the Marquee. Could you give some example about Marquee usage;And i don't want to set the initial status of progress bar to be continous or blocks becuase there will be flash when i change the style of progress bar to be Marquee..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Hey, if you have synchronous blocking job on main/GUI thread you won't escape nasty things with `Marque`.

Marque WON'T create separate thread for its animation!

You have to `DoEvents` or anything similar to that for example run the dialog with the Marque on separate thread.

Comment: thanks ! yes ,i implemented with Continous style using backgroudworker ,it's works well very now. i think Marque Style maybe need the same way to implement.